# Return a value if a time is within two given time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script that would insert an attendance of the student. I want to insert in the attendance status, **if the time() is between 5AM to 7:30AM** then my compareTime function should return P or Present and **if time() is between 7:31 and 8:30** then the function should return L or Late. I can't seem to get the proper return value with this comparison between time. I badly need help.

Here is my code:

```
function compareTime($time,$grade){
if ($grade == "H1" || $grade == "H2" || $grade == "H3" || $grade == "H4" || $grade == "S1" || $grade == "S2") {
   if ($time > strtotime('07:30:00') && $time < strtotime('8:30:00')){
        return "L";
    } else if ($time > strtotime('05:00:00') && $time <= strtotime('7:30:00')){
        return "P";
    }
} else {
    if ($time > strtotime('07:15:00') && $time < strtotime('8:30:00')){
        return "L";
    } else if ($time > strtotime('05:00:00') && $time <= strtotime('7:30:00')){
        return "P";
    }
}
```

Insert Code:

```
function recordAttendance($conn, $sid, $glid, $scid){
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tbl_attendance(student_id, gradeLevel_id, section_id, date, arrival_time, status) VALUES ('".$sid."', '".$glid."', '".$scid."', CURDATE(), CURTIME(), '".compareTime(time(),$glid)."')")or die(mysqli_error());
```

**UPDATE:** I have fixed it out. The reason why the function does not return the exact value is because of the timezone nothing being set. Therefore, whenever I get date('Y-m-d H:i:s') it does not match the date and time of my machine. By adding **date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');** fixed my problem. Thanks everyone who helped!

Comment: Why not just use `case` in your `select` query later and return `p` when in the right range or `l` when outside?

Comment: What's the output of $time in the function? Maybe the format is different? Another option is that the comparison is a "string" comparison which will cause unplanned results.

Comment: @chris85 We could use that. But what we want is to store the returned value in our status column for future purposes.

Comment: @OfirBaruch it's in this format 1502675521. That is also why i used strtotime in my pre defined time to match it. Am I wrong?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) drivers. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Answer (score 0):

For all strtotime add date also

```
   strtotime('2017-08-14 07:30:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `strtotime('05:00:00')` use `strtotime('today')+86400*5;` (timestamp of 00:00 today + 5 hours)

Comment: Is it possible to compare time in this format 'H:i:s'?

Comment: try this - strtotime('today 07:30:00');   "today %your time%"

Comment: strtotime('today 07:30:00'); doesn't work. Do you have any solution for this? All I really want is to return "P" if the insert time of data is between 5AM to 7:30AM. This problem have cracked my head for days.

Comment: I noticed that when I echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') it does not equal or match the date and time on my machine. Why is that?